# While executing appium test on android device, is it possible to type text using the android keyboard

Tags: webdriver, appium

I am testing android device using appium from Mac machine. Sendkeys is failing on a particular page. Following is the description of the issue i already posted. [Sendkeys fails on android appium driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529900/sendkeys-fails-on-android-appium-driver).
So I want to know is there any other possibilites to resolve the issue. I spent hours in searching answer for it. But all i can find is pressing back, home buttons. I want to type  characters like 'k' , 's' using the android keyboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using trying with ruby refer this: [http://rubydoc.info/github/songkick/appium-ios-driver/master/frames/UIAutomation/Keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

you can use virtual keyboard on simulator.
if you use genymotion emulator, you can choose to set use or not use virtual keyboard.
and if you use send_keys function failed, you can try element.set_text('your text') instead(python client)

in my case, when i run test on a real device, default call out the android keyboard.

maybe you can provide more details, paste your scripts etc.