# Appium 3.4.1 sendKey() not working with Android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium 3.4.1, Android v4.4.2 with Java for automation testing for Android App. I have got stuck for sending values to editText box which activate numeric keyboard when focusing on field. However, when I clear the field it works, when I click in field it works but when I sendKeys to field it does not work. It type the value to other fields. I have tried all the possible ways based on below links. Also, there are fields on multiple screen which open numeric keyboard when focusing and sendkeys method is working for those field.

Is there any way where we can use the android keyboard to type value in field using Appium

1. https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-sendkeys-function-clicks-taps-random-elements-in-the-page-but-does-not-enter-text-in-the-edittext-element/2095
2. https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-3-3-sendkeys-not-working-properly/2074

I would appreciate your inputs on this.

Code :

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("com.intellih.mobile:id/edt_caloriesBurned_work‌​out_add_exercise_MS")); 
element.clear(); 
element.click(); 
element=driver.findElement(By.id("com.intellih.mobile:id/edt_caloriesBurned_work‌​out_add_exercise_MS")); 
element.sendKeys("55");
```

Comment: Here are few more links which I have used: 3. https://discuss.appium.io/t/sendkeys-and-click-function-does-not-work-for-ios-simulator/5896 
4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529900/sendkeys-fails-on-android-appium-driver
5. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4297

Comment: could you share the code you've tried as well

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks for your response!!!! `WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id("com.intellih.mobile:id/edt_caloriesBurned_workout_add_exercise_MS"));
element.clear();
element.click();
element=driver.findElement(By.id("com.intellih.mobile:id/edt_caloriesBurned_workout_add_exercise_MS"));
element.sendKeys("55");`

Comment: what does adding `System.out.println(element.getAttribute("className") )` to your code after `element` is defined display?

Comment: On console it display `android.widget.EditText` when I run `System.out.println(element.getAttribute("className") )`

Comment: please add the appium server logs and code to the question in that case

Comment: you can download the log from here http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=00620222351464733278&t=0062022235146473327869080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the field and then run below command

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_NUMPAD_5";

This will type 5 in the field you can run multiple command on same field.